# jquery scrolls up instead of down

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate, scrolltop

```
<article>
  <aside>
    ...
    <div id="onlineformular">
        ...
    </div>
  </aside>
</article>

article
{
  overflow:auto;
  max-height:77vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color:white;
}

$('article').animate({scrollTop:$('#onlineformular').position().top}, 'slow');
```

I simply want to scroll down to div#onlineformular, but it scrolls up. Why? (only snippets shown)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a full working example that shows this problem?

Comment: It's too much text from many different files. I read a lot about not working scrolling and I wonder if there is a solution to simply make it working for every case. I haven't found a solution yet for this case. Of course I'll answer questions.

Comment: Only the scrollTop value seems to be wrong. How can I get the correct value?

Answer (score 0):

According to code provided by you, page will scroll according to the position of div#onlineformular from page top.

animate will animate scroll from current scroll position to the new scroll position from top defined by position of div#onlineformular from top.

Comment: Thank you, but the position of div#onlineformular seems to be wrong, so it scrolls up away from div#onlineformular. It seems to me that there are general problems with this scrolling, according to so many internet questions. Maybe any general problems with viewport or outer divs? Is there an alternative for position().top that delivers the correct value?

Comment: Check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/tv268vwq/ 
Page is scrolling up and down as expected on click on button.

Comment: position().top you are calculating from top of article tag. it should be document  `$('document').animate({scrollTop:$('#onlineformular').position().top}, 'slow');  `

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't scroll at all. Is there a middle course?

Comment: $('window').animate({scrollTop:$('#onlineformular').positi‌​on().top}, 'slow');

Answer (score 0):

Use `body` selector instead of `article`:

```js
$('body').animate({scrollTop:$('#onlineformular').position().top}, 'slow');
```

```css
.some_div{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #adadad;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='some_div'></div>
<article>
  <aside>
    ...
    <div id="onlineformular">
        ...
    </div>
    
  </aside>
</article>
```

Comment: Thank you, but the article tag is scrollable, the body is fixed. But I'll try it... Unfortunately it doesn't scroll at all now.

Comment: @user3756502, sorry, but without seeing the whole code I can't determine what the problem is. It can even be a `CSS` problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with [$('#onlineformular').ScrollTo();](http://balupton.github.io/jquery-scrollto/)

Very easy.